# Pyspark - how to generate random numbers within a certain range of a column value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, random, pyspark

Initially I wanted to generate random integers between two numbers (10 and 80):

```
from random import randint
df.fillna(randint(10, 80), 'score').show()
```

What will be a correct way to generate random decimals within a certain range of a current column's value? For example, random decimals within +/- 15% of a `'score'` column with a value 25.0?

I've looked into the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions) but there are only examples showing how to generate random numbers with seed. Not sure that it is suitable in this case.

Comment: Just divide by 100 or 10

Comment: import random

>>> random_decimal = random.randint(100, 1000)/100
>>> print(random_decimal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm reading this right, but you're looking to find a range of random floats between 21.25 and 28.75? If so:

```
score = 25.0
left_most_column =  score - (score*0.15) #21.25
right_most_column =  score + (score*0.15) #28.75
answer = random.uniform(left_most_column, right_most_column)
```

`Uniform` is the key function here.

Answer (score 1):

```py
# Imports
from random import choice, randint

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, StructField, StructType

# Variable setup
rand_range = 0.15
schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("score", IntegerType(), nullable=False),
        StructField("random_score", IntegerType(), nullable=True),
    ]
)
data = list()

# Create the score column data
for i in range(0, 50):
    data.append(
        {
            "score": randint(10, 80),
        }
    )

# Create the Spark dataframe
df = SQLContext.createDataFrame(data, schema)

# Generate the randomized score column
df = df.withColumn(
    "random_score",
    F.col("score") +
    (choice([-1, 1]) *
     randint(
         F.col("score") * (1 - rand_range), 
         F.col("score") * (1 + rand_range)
     ))
)
```

Most of the top is boilerplate, but the magic happens at the bottom.

1. Take the score column
2. Create a random number between +/- 15% of that value
3. Multiple by a random +/- 1 to give the addition or subtraction.

Comment: The original question asked for decimals, in which case you'd need to change the `random_score` type fo `FloatType`