# How to generate random numbers within a range defined by other columns

Tags: python, pyspark, random

I have a dataframe with two integer columns:

```py
data = [("A",1, 5), ("B",3, 8), ("C",2, 7)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["type","min", "max"])
```

I'm trying to use `random.randrange(start,stop,step)` to generate random numbers within the min/max range provided by the columns for each type and (obviously) failing.

I'm stumped! I think I'm trying to use a function designed to be used on explicit data, on columns of data - but I'm not sure how to get around that.

I tried:

```py
df = df.withColumn("rand",randrange(col("min"),col("max")))
```

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'Column'

I also tried:

```py
def rando(start,stop):
    return randrange(start,stop)
randoUDF = F.udf(rando,IntegerType())
df = df.withColumn("rand",randoUDF("min","max"))
```

> 'ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0,0,0)'
> Same outcome for `df = df.withColumn("rand",randoUDF(col("min"),col("max")))`

The min,max columns are definitely fully populated...

Questions I've looked at (not exhaustive!):

- [Generate 'n' unique random numbers within a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842289/generate-n-unique-random-numbers-within-a-range)

  Not quite right
- [Pyspark - how to generate random numbers within a certain range of a column value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62701828/pyspark-how-to-generate-random-numbers-within-a-certain-range-of-a-column-valu)

  Theoretically I could use the way the score column is generated but there's millions of rows in the dataset so this feels like a bad solution

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can achieve the same result with some basic math :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("rand", F.rand() * (F.col("max") - F.col("min")) + F.col("min"))
```

The new columns will be in float but you can either trunc it or round it depending on your usecase.

---

if you want to use the random package, you need an UDF. You almost did it. I just fixed your code :

```py
import random
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T

randoUDF = F.udf(random.randrange, T.IntegerType())
df.withColumn("rand", randoUDF(F.col("min"), F.col("max"))).show()
```